# Google login with firebase takes longer time to authenticate on mobile browser as compared to web

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Google login with Firebase in my web application, and it works smoothly and quickly. However, I've noticed a significant delay when testing on mobile browser. The redirect to the next screen after a successful login takes considerably more time on mobile.

**Scenario:**

I have a web page where users can log in using their Google accounts with Firebase authentication. The login process involves the use of `firebaseLoginWithGoogle` function, which works well on web browsers.

**Problem:**

1. **Delay on Mobile Web Browser:** When users try to log in on mobile web browser(smartphones and tablets), there is a noticeable delay in the redirection to the next screen after successful login. On web browsers, this delay is not observed.
2. **Performance:** I have reviewed the code and ensured that the Firebase authentication and database interactions are properly optimized. However, the delay persists on mobile.

**Additional Information:**

- I am using React for the web application.
- The code is asynchronous and utilizes `async/await` for handling Firebase authentication and database operations.

Here is the custom `loginWithGoogleFunction` I've been using:

```
const firebaseLoginWithGoogle = async () => {
  const firebaseGoogleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebaseGoogleProvider.addScope("email");
  firebaseGoogleProvider.addScope("profile");

  try {
    const result = await signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth, firebaseGoogleProvider);
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential?.accessToken;
    const user = result.user;

    const userInfoFromDb = await firebaseGetUserInfoFromDb(user.uid);

    if (!userInfoFromDb) {
      const newUserDoc = {
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        uid: user.uid,
        profileUrl: user.photoURL,
        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        apiKey: uuidv4(),
        isEmailVerified: true,
        accountPlan: "basic",
        maxResponsesLimit: 50,
        notificationSettings: {
          email: [user.email],
          enable: false,
          isMultiEmails: false,
        },
      };
      await setDoc(doc(firebaseDb, "users", user.uid), newUserDoc);

      return { credential, token, user };
    } else {
      return { credential, token, user };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};
```

Reference Site:
I have also observed a similar behavior on an existing site: https://slack-clone-ozngrsc.web.app/. When you open this site with a mobile device, you can find a minor delay during the login process.

**Question:**

1. What could be the potential reasons for this behavior? Why does Google login with Firebase take longer time  on mobile devices?
2. Are there any specific optimizations or best practices I should consider to improve the login performance on mobile?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or advice on how to address this issue and ensure a smoother login experience on both web and mobile. Thank you for your assistance!